# Is the V2 authorization endpoint fully implemented in Azure Government?

Tags: azure-ad-msal, azure-gov

I am using MSAL.JS to attempt to acquire a token within a single-page application (SPA).

This is the authority URI that we are seeing in the traces:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.us/organizations/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

This produces the following error:

> AADSTS50038: The API version isn't supported
>   
> Trace ID: 38d01881-d864-4ba4-b3d5-c168739f0900
>   
> Correlation ID: e9eb70cb-5774-4579-a113-53c4ca762d90
>   
> Timestamp: 2018-04-18 15:42:16Z

If I login to the portal with my credentials then call the SPA, the app authenticates and I can continue to use it. I think this is because of the browser caching the session and login information and never making the call to the V2.0 endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Received the answer to this question on a separate thread.

**At present, the V2 application model is not fully implemented or supported in any sovereign cloud (Azure Government, Azure China, Azure Germany).**

Once the model is tested and proven in the public cloud, it will be ported to the government clouds.